# I get a "bad login" message when trying to play multiplayer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to play multiplayer I type in the only server I know, which the game says was right, then click Play and it loads. Then it says **Can't connect to server: bad log in**. How can I fix this?

Comment: We are going to need more information in order to help you, there are just too many things that could be happening. Illegal credentials, pirated copy, connectivity issues...

Comment: Are you using a valid username and password to a paid account? If you are verify that you have everything typed in correctly.

Comment: I recommend you just Google for a server that allows offline mode.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot login to a server that has the `online-mode` set to `true` in `server.properties` when you're in offline mode, sorry. Some servers allow offline-mode connections, but this is rare since it is open to those who pirated the game and you could pretend to have any username.

Comment: Ahh thank you anyway. It was helpful actually. If you didn't say that I would have gone crazy with other questions.

Comment: No problem. Sorry it's not exactly a solution :-/ You should try to figure out why you can't login despite a working internet connection, maybe your firewall blocks the Minecraft launcher

Comment: also, even if your login works, another reason for not being able to connect to a server may be that they run a different (usually older) version than your client, google for MCnostalgia in that case

Comment: Oh, and I'm asking another question soon. If you ever find it give me a answer :]

Comment: well, I can simply click your name to find it

Answer (score 2):

You will get a “Bad Login” error from a specific server if that server can't reach `minecraft.net` to verify your account.

This means that if the *server* has a hard time connecting to `minecraft.net` (either because `minecraft.net` has just gone down, or because the server has an unreliable network route to `minecraft.net`) even if *you* have no problem connecting to `minecraft.net` to login to your account initially, then you will get intermittent "Bad Login" errors from the server that's having network problems.