# Why does nothing happen when I register and log in to my paid Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I registered 6 files in minecraft. None of them are available to log into. I even wrote them down but it still won't work. And I have to play offline and multiplayer won't work on offline.

Comment: Is this the same issue as [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50820/i-get-a-bad-login-message-when-trying-to-play-multiplayer)?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: Seeing both questions are by the same person, I'd say it's pretty likely.

Comment: I'm not sure it's an ongoing problem, but there have been issues with people selling stolen/hacked "gift codes" to Minecraft from third-party websites. If you were had by a thief, and bought stolen credentials (i.e. didn't buy from minecraft.net), those would likely be canceled.

Comment: Thats not a great deal of information to go by... more details please?

Comment: This is not a dupe, but it's impossible to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Well, judging by the fact that you said "TNT", I assume you mean you want to play on "retail" servers as opposed to "classic" servers.

In order to do this, you need to buy the game. To buy the game, you need to log into the account you created and then press "Buy Game" on [Minecraft.net](http://www.minecraft.net/). Simply creating an account, which I assume is what you were doing, only works on "Classic" servers.

If you did actually buy 6 Minecraft accounts, I suggest contacting [Mojang Support](http://help.mojang.com/%5C).

Comment: Ive bought quite a few copies of the game, but only ever needed one account for that... No idea why you would need 6 of them.. The login server has never had an issue with me running two clients at once from the same machine (So I can copy a creative world creation into my living world :D)

Answer (score 5):

Can you also not login to http://www.minecraft.net/login?

If you happen to have bought Minecraft around Jan 19, there seems to have been an issue with Mojang's system:

> [The Mojang Team @MojangTeam
>
>   If you purchased Minecraft in the last 48 hours, there was a problem with your order. Sending refunds to those who did not receive the game.](https://twitter.com/#!/MojangTeam/status/160037042783387648)

Also,

> [Debbi @Debbi29
>
>   @MojangTeam cannot login since new version came out. no support. you take our money and you don't care.
>
>   The Mojang Team @MojangTeam
>
>   @Debbi29 Hi Debbi, will you please email help@mojang.com? Someone will be able to help you from there.](https://twitter.com/#!/MojangTeam/status/154592895507234817)

Maybe you should also send them an email, help@mojang.com